# My Debian apt-get doesn't have search function, why?

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I have used some version of apt-get that had **apt-get search jetty**, that would return list of all packages that contain word jetty. But when I type apt-get I get following list of commands:

```
apt 0.8.10.3 for i386 compiled on Apr 15 2011 21:02:20
Usage: apt-get [options] command
       apt-get [options] install|remove pkg1 [pkg2 ...]
       apt-get [options] source pkg1 [pkg2 ...]

apt-get is a simple command line interface for downloading and
installing packages. The most frequently used commands are update
and install.

Commands:
   update - Retrieve new lists of packages
   upgrade - Perform an upgrade
   install - Install new packages (pkg is libc6 not libc6.deb)
   remove - Remove packages
   autoremove - Remove automatically all unused packages
   purge - Remove packages and config files
   source - Download source archives
   build-dep - Configure build-dependencies for source packages
   dist-upgrade - Distribution upgrade, see apt-get(8)
   dselect-upgrade - Follow dselect selections
   clean - Erase downloaded archive files
   autoclean - Erase old downloaded archive files
   check - Verify that there are no broken dependencies
   markauto - Mark the given packages as automatically installed
   unmarkauto - Mark the given packages as manually installed

Options:
  -h  This help text.
  -q  Loggable output - no progress indicator
  -qq No output except for errors
  -d  Download only - do NOT install or unpack archives
  -s  No-act. Perform ordering simulation
  -y  Assume Yes to all queries and do not prompt
  -f  Attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place
  -m  Attempt to continue if archives are unlocatable
  -u  Show a list of upgraded packages as well
  -b  Build the source package after fetching it
  -V  Show verbose version numbers
  -c=? Read this configuration file
  -o=? Set an arbitrary configuration option, eg -o dir::cache=/tmp
See the apt-get(8), sources.list(5) and apt.conf(5) manual
pages for more information and options.
                       This APT has Super Cow Powers.
```

Is my apt-get old version or why it doesn't have that search command? This might be stupid question for all super users, but I'm newbie and I don't know these kind of things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `aptitude search` or `apt-cache search`.

Comment: So I remembered wrong, it was different command.